# Inserting row for every missed number in a sequence

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to insert a row for every missed number in my sequence. For example, I have "35C-1412-K01" and "35C-1421" and the idea is to add a row for every missed number between 1412 to 1421. I have done this before however, the code that I used does not work for this one due to the fact that the code compares the last 5 characters in the cell and I am looking more into the middle number of that cell. My idea is to possibly use the "MID" property and not the "RIGHT" property but I am having trouble implementing that. I also have some cells that have more than three characters before the first "-" i.e "35TC-1411" so that could possibly throw off the code if it only accounts for there to be only three characters. Any help in this is greatly appreciated.

Code that I referenced above:

```
Option Explicit
Sub InsertNullTest()
Dim i As Long, gap As Long
Dim WorkRng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range To Check", Title:="Select a Range", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If WorkRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| check user hasn't canceled the dialog box
With WorkRng
    For i = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        gap = Right(.Cells(i), 5) - Right(.Cells(i - 1), 5)
        If gap > 1 Then .Cells(i).Resize(gap - 1).Insert xlDown
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Split. This code assumes the first and third elements of your strings are constant.

```
Sub InsertNullTest()

Dim i As Long, v1, v2, j As Long
Dim WorkRng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range To Check", Title:="Select a Range", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If WorkRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| check user hasn't canceled the dialog box

With WorkRng
    For i = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        v1 = Split(.Cells(i), "-")
        v2 = Split(.Cells(i - 1), "-")
        If Val(v1(1) - v2(1)) > 1 Then
            .Cells(i).Resize(Val(v1(1) - v2(1)) - 1).Insert xlDown
            For j = 1 To Val(v1(1) - v2(1)) - 1
                .Cells(i - 1).Offset(j) = v2(0) & "-" & Val(v2(1)) + j & "-" & v2(2)
            Next j
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it to just look at the numeric value of the tag number? I just realized that some of the cells contain tags such as "35E-1401AK" followed by "35E-1408". When the code is run against these two tags I should get an inserted rows however I am getting an error. Other than that it seems to be working

Comment: If you read up on Split, you'll work it out. In your original example of 35C-1412-K01, v1(0)=35C, v1(1)=1412, v(2)=K01. It returns an array split on the delimiter you specify. So yes it will error if there is only one hyphen.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I should have mentioned that one could probably allow for variations such as the one you cite as long as there is some pattern, e.g. 4 numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?